# Is it possible to monitor a directory for modifications using Javascript

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I'm writing a Image gallery using Qt/QML and I want to show all images in a folder, for example, named **img**. Adding all of the pictures in this folder to a model like this

```
ListModel {
        ListElement {
            img:"img/1.jpg"
            img_big :"img/1_big.jpg";

        }

        ListElement {
            img_big :"img/2_big.jpg";
            img:"img/2.jpg"
        }
}
```

Which is hard coded in a .qml file is not a perfect way. Is it possible to monitor this directory for new files and add them to this model?
I know that I can use **QFileSystemWatcher** but I want to know that whether I can use javascript to do so or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such provision in the current drafts of the [HTML5 File API](http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/), so you won't be able to do this with pure JavaScript.